# Polyglossia \setdefaultlanguage seems to break French quotes

Tags: punctuation, polyglossia, french

This might be more of a bug report than a proper question, but here goes.

In the following example, compiled with `lualatex`, the sequence `<<` is translated to an opening French quotation mark ("guillemet") as expected, but the closing `>>` is not:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\begin{document}
<<Test>>
\end{document}
```

[image: incorrect substitution for <code>>></code>]

Commenting out `\setdefaultlanguage{french}` fixes the problem but is obviously not a satisfying solution.

Using `xelatex` or the `csquotes` package works on this example, but would require more work (many individual documents and/or configuration files to change in my particular case).

Any hint or explanation would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the file `polyglossia-frpt.lua`; line 122

```
122  [byte('>')] = {left,  thinspace},
```

should be

```
122  [byte('›')] = {left,  thinspace},
```

(I left the line number for reference).

If I make a copy of the distributed file in the working directory and do the change, I get the expected output.

[image]

Comment: Sent issue report at https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/124